# Failed Pyinstaller in normal and virtual environments

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Simply trying convert a 'Hello World' Program (.py -> .exe) using pyinstaller (-V 4.1)

Using `Python 3.9.1`::
`Windows 10`

Running in normal cmd this is a summary of the error messages:

```
D:\> pyinstaller hello_world.py

win32ctypes.pywin32.pywintypes.error: (1920, 'LoadLibraryExW', 'The file cannot be accessed by the system.')
```

I have seen other posts suggesting to run `pyinstaller` in a virtual environment. This will run further but still breaks with an error.
Running in a venv, this is a summary of the error messages:

```
(test_env) D:\> pyinstaller hello_world.py

5824 WARNING: Can not get binary dependencies for file: C:\Users\%User%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe

5825 WARNING:   Reason: 'The file is empty'

OSError: Python library not found: libpython39m.dll, libpython3.9.dll, libpython3.9m.dll, python39.dll, libpython39.dll
```

Thank you in advance,
I'm sure this an overlooked simple fix

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error, and the problem on my case was using python from the Microsoft Store. So I downloaded python again from [Python WebSite](https://python.org) and installed it on a especific directory (something like: `C:\path\to\my\directory\`

The the only thing you need to do after this is run the virtual enviorement using the `-p` flag(considering that your `hello_world.py` is on `D:\`):

```
D:\> virtualenv -p C:\path\to\my\directory\python D:\
```

then install the `pyinstaller` on that enviorement:

```
D:\> Scripts\activate
(test_env) D:\> pip install pyinstaller
```

and there it is:

```
(test_env) D:\> pyinstaller hello_world.py
(test_env) D:\> cd dist\
(test_env) D:\> .\hello_world
```